# Separate DbContext replaced for Integration testing with WebApplicationFactory not executing migrations

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, webapi

Im writing integration tests for my WebAPI and for them im swapping implementation of DbContext that my app is using. I'm doing this so I can run configurations that seed my DB with data that are necessary for testing.

My test DbContext inherits from DbContext used by my app and it looks like this:

```
{
    public TestNeverLateContext(DbContextOptions<NeverLateContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(GetType().Assembly);
    }
}
```

The problem is that while i swap this implementation my WebApi is not performing migrations. While DB is created migrations column is created but its not populated.
I guess it is because migration classes contain this attribute

```
[DbContext(typeof(NeverLateContext))]
```

Is there a way to execute those migrations with my inherited TestNeverLateContext?
I could just copy this migrations and recreate them with

```
[DbContext(typeof(TestNeverLateContext))]
```

but maybe there is another approach.

Comment: Not sure why you need to inherit the context?

Comment: So i can override OnModelCreating and add configurations that are specified in integration tests assembly. This configurations seed my DB while tests are running. But i might got something wrong.